# Google Charts automated/background processing

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to figure out how to create a script/process to automatically generate **Google Charts** and save them as png's.  My application displays temperature data to users, but on a monthly basis we archive a report as a **pdf**.  I currently use `pchart` to generate an image server side, so it is easy to accomplish this.  Is there a way to programmatically generate the image from the Google Chart?

I understand I can use `getImageURI()` on the web page, but I do not know how to do this without the browser.

Comment: `getImageURI()` returns a base64 _string_ -- you should be able to save the _string_ to a file -- with the extension `.png`

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS seems to be the answer.  This allows me to create a PHP script to render the chart and capture the image.  Just what I need.